# GCP, RabbitMQ click-to-deploy service, can't find RabbitMQ logs

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, rabbitmq

I see that the RabbitMQ cluster initiates connection termination in my application logs. So I'd like to find out a reason. Click-to-deploy GCP's service was used to deploy a pretty standard RabbitMQ cluster. According to official RabbitMQ docs, the default logs location is `$RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE/$RABBITMQ_NODENAME.log`, however the `$RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE` isn't even set. The only env variable related to logs set is `RABBITMQ_LOGS=-`, which AFAICS resolves to sending all the logs to a `stdout` rather then a file.

So the question is: what should I do to find my logs (if there do exist and I missed something) or how can I modify my env/rabbitmq configuration file to ensure logs are written and accessible.

Comment: Did you check stackdriver?

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, I am pretty new to the GCP and might miss something. What's that? Additional logging aggregation service?

Comment: Yep, nearly everything in GCP will be logged in the StackDriver service.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, ouh, I'll try that, I made it old-fashioned way by interacting with container's bash via the console simulator GCP provides.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer, well, I see nothing rabbitmq-specific there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of RabbitMQ log file is /var/log/rabbitmq/log/ .

You can login your pod via command, I recommend this link for [Get-shell-running-container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/):

gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME] --zone [ZONE_NAME] --project [PROJECT_NAME]  && kubectl exec -it [POD_NAME] -c rabbitmq -- /bin/bash

You have to enable “Stackdriver Metrics Exporter” when you use Click-to-deploy and config RabbitMQ,  and then you can use tool “log viewer” to set filter and export logs in stackdriver.